# steamVR run grab code logic into startTouching event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality

I am a little bit new to VR using HTC-Vive with [steamVR toolkit][1]. I have came across a problem where I have startTouching event which fires
         as controller start touching with object but for some reason i want to run 'grab event code logic' into start touching event. I am unable to identify
         grab event code. How can i do that?